Unstable WI-FI on Intel Alder Lake network card
For some weeks now, I have a Dell XPS 13 2022 with the following network card :
Intel Alder Lake-P PCH CNVi WiFi
$ lshw -C network
 *-network
       description: Interface réseau sans fil
       produit: Alder Lake-P PCH CNVi WiFi
       fabriquant: Intel Corporation
       identifiant matériel: 14.3
       information bus: pci@0000:00:14.3
       nom logique: wlp0s20f3
       version: 01
       numéro de série: a0:02:a5:9e:9d:41
       bits: 64 bits
       horloge: 33MHz
       fonctionnalités: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=6.6.59_1 firmware=83.e8f84e98.0 so-a0-gf-a0-83.uc ip=192.168.1.47 latency=0 link=yes
multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       ressources: mémoireE/S:600-5ff irq:16 mémoire:607a294000-607a297fff

And since the beginning, I have a very unstable connectivity. I use the same SSID/router/software to connect to WI-FI (actually wpa_cli) than my previous laptop, on the same GNU/Linux distrib (void linux) and in the previous one I had no issues like this. It disconnects randomly, and take a long time of trials and errors before catching a connection again.
Here is a sample of the wpa_cli output :
<3>CTRL-EVENT-NETWORK-NOT-FOUND
<3>CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-STARTED
<3>CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-RESULTS
<3>WPS-AP-AVAILABLE
<3>CTRL-EVENT-NETWORK-NOT-FOUND
<3>CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-STARTED
<3>CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-RESULTS
<3>WPS-AP-AVAILABLE
<3>CTRL-EVENT-NETWORK-NOT-FOUND
<3>CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-RESULTS
<3>WPS-AP-AVAILABLE
<3>CTRL-EVENT-NETWORK-NOT-FOUND
<3>CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-RESULTS
<3>WPS-AP-AVAILABLE
<3>CTRL-EVENT-SSID-REENABLED id=2 ssid="Pretty Fly for A WI-FI"
<3>Added BSSID f4:ca:e5:e6:01:a0 into ignore list, ignoring for 10 seconds
<3>SME: Trying to authenticate with f4:ca:e5:e6:01:a0 (SSID='Pretty Fly for A WI-FI' freq=2462 MHz)
<3>Trying to associate with f4:ca:e5:e6:01:a0 (SSID='Pretty Fly for A WI-FI' freq=2462 MHz)
<3>Associated with f4:ca:e5:e6:01:a0
<3>CTRL-EVENT-SUBNET-STATUS-UPDATE status=0
<3>CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED bssid=f4:ca:e5:e6:01:a0 reason=7
<3>BSSID f4:ca:e5:e6:01:a0 ignore list count incremented to 2, ignoring for 10 seconds
<3>CTRL-EVENT-SSID-TEMP-DISABLED id=2 ssid="Pretty Fly for A WI-FI" auth_failures=3 duration=49 reason=CONN_FAILED
<3>CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-STARTED
<3>CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-RESULTS
<3>WPS-AP-AVAILABLE
<3>Removed BSSID f4:ca:e5:e6:01:a0 from ignore list (clear)
<3>CTRL-EVENT-NETWORK-NOT-FOUND
<3>CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-STARTED
<3>CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-RESULTS
<3>WPS-AP-AVAILABLE
<3>CTRL-EVENT-NETWORK-NOT-FOUND
<3>CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-STARTED
<3>CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-RESULTS
<3>WPS-AP-AVAILABLE
<3>CTRL-EVENT-NETWORK-NOT-FOUND
<3>CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-RESULTS
<3>WPS-AP-AVAILABLE
<3>CTRL-EVENT-NETWORK-NOT-FOUND
<3>CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-RESULTS
<3>WPS-AP-AVAILABLE
<3>CTRL-EVENT-NETWORK-NOT-FOUND
<3>CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-RESULTS
<3>WPS-AP-AVAILABLE
<3>CTRL-EVENT-SSID-REENABLED id=2 ssid="Pretty Fly for A WI-FI"
<3>Added BSSID f4:ca:e5:e6:01:a0 into ignore list, ignoring for 10 seconds
<3>SME: Trying to authenticate with f4:ca:e5:e6:01:a0 (SSID='Pretty Fly for A WI-FI' freq=2462 MHz)
<3>Trying to associate with f4:ca:e5:e6:01:a0 (SSID='Pretty Fly for A WI-FI' freq=2462 MHz)
<3>Associated with f4:ca:e5:e6:01:a0
<3>CTRL-EVENT-SUBNET-STATUS-UPDATE status=0
<3>WPA: Key negotiation completed with f4:ca:e5:e6:01:a0 [PTK=CCMP GTK=CCMP]
<3>Removed BSSID f4:ca:e5:e6:01:a0 from ignore list
<3>CTRL-EVENT-CONNECTED - Connection to f4:ca:e5:e6:01:a0 completed [id=2 id_str=]

It's a short one, because it sometimes takes more than 30 minutes to reconnect...
Does anyone have an idea ?


Make sure you're running Linux 6.11.7 2. Make sure you have the latest firmware installed 3. Make sure you are not using WPA3. If it still doesn't work, file a bug report here: https://bugzilla.kernel.org/enter_bug.cgi?product=Drivers - under Wireless-Intel


I'm actually using Linux 6.6.59_11, the last available kernel on VoidLinux. For the firmware, I have both ipw2100-firmware-1.3_6 and ipw2200-firmware-3.1_6 installed.
About WPA3, I don't know how/where to check this with wpa_cli ?
